# XSLT to copy from two tags with index attribute 1/2 in one single tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML like this:

```
    <tns:name2List>
        <tns:name2 index="1">Name</tns:name2>
        <tns:name2 index="2">A</tns:name2>
        <tns:name2 index="1">Surname</tns:name2>
        <tns:name2 index="2">B</tns:name2>
    </tns:name2List>
```

And I would need to obtain something like this:

```
<name2List>
    <name>Name A</name>
    <name>Name B</name>
</name2List>
```

Do you know how can I do this with an XSLT 1.0? Thanks!

I tried something like:

```
 <xsl:template match="/tns:name2List/tns:name2">
    <name>
         <xsl:for-each select="/tns:name2List/tns:name2">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </name>
 </xsl:template>
```

but I get some:

```
<name>
    <name>Name A Name B </name>
    <name>Name A Name B </name>
    <name>Name A Name B </name>
    <name>Name A Name B </name>
</name>
```

How can I change it to make the desired output?

Comment: The example is ambiguous. Please explain the exact logic that should be applied here.

Comment: Well, I would need to concatenate the two tags with <name2> followed by index "1" and "2" into one tag <name>. I tried some things but I get 4 tags, and I would need only 2 (from this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given example, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/tns:name2List">
    <name2List>
        <xsl:for-each select="tns:name2[@index=1]">
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::tns:name2"/>
            </name>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </name2List>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this assumes that the input is arranged in pairs - so that every `tns:name2` element with `index` value of 1 is immediately followed by another `tns:name2` element with `index` value of 2. If this assumption is false, then try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::tns:name2[1][@index=2]"/>
```